# Regarding share link task in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am developing an app in **windows phone 8**.

I am using **ShareLinkTask** to post my app store link to social networking sites like twitter, face book, whats app...etc .

I am executing it in **Emulator**. The Emulator does not showing anything just showing black screen by clicking on the share link task button.

I am saw some posts on this site saying that the menu opens automatically in device , is it true? or I have to write the code link by clicking on share link task button displaying a popup containing list of sites to user , and code behind for those buttons in the popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in **Emulator we can not install apps from App Store** so in Emulator you can not test that thing.

You just need to **Deploy your Application to Device and test it** and check whether its going as per your Requirement or not.

you can use **ShareLinkTask** as shown Below :

```
ShareLinkTask shareLinkTask = new ShareLinkTask();
shareLinkTask.Title = "Code Samples";
shareLinkTask.LinkUri = new Uri("http://code.msdn.com/wpapps", UriKind.Absolute);
shareLinkTask.Message = "Here are some great code samples for Windows Phone.";
shareLinkTask.Show();
```

for more Reference you can check here [How to use the share link task for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394009(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: If my answer helped you or its answer for your Question, please mark as answered